# Kendo-grid custom aggregate in footer template by columns values

Tags: count, kendo-grid, aggregate

I have a large grid and I need to add a count in the footer, to calculate count of non-nullable and not empty cells in column, but standart count aggregate gives only completed total count result. In custon templates I find ability only for using these completed aggregation functions (min, max, sum, count...). Is there any ideas how to count only filled cells in column and display result in footer of grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone interests how I have solved it, I will answer in general.

I have created custom column in result's data (before binding it to grid) with values 1 or 0: 1 - if I want to count current row in result; 0 - if I don't. Then I have used `sum` aggregate function for this column instead `count`. And then I just only have not displayed this column in grid for users.

This approach gives ability to write your custom logic outside of kendo footer template, you just use `count` (in this case `sum`) for results of your custom logic.

All other approaches and solutions, which I've tried did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the [columns.footerTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.footerTemplate) property as a function, and use some custom logic to count the non-null fields, then display it in the footer of the respective column, e.g.:

[Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/iKuCO/7)